# authorise view user to not access some pages in rails4 app by using cancancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan, cancancan

Am using Devise for authentication and cancancan for authorization.Now i want to not allow the view user for some pages. So i add following codes. But it throws undefined local variable or method `current_user' for # error.

My ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(dashboard_user)

       current_dashboard_user ||= DashboardUser.new 
       if current_dashboard_user.CD_DASHBOARD_ADMIN?
         can :manage, :all
       else
         can :read, :summary
         can :read, :home
       end
      .........
  end
```

Application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  before_action :authenticate_dashboard_user!

  protected
   rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to main_app.root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end
  ....
end
```

dashboard_user_controller.rb

```
class DashboardUsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_dashboard_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  load_and_authorize_resource
  ....
end
```

Comment: Can you tell me where you define your current user? or for which model you are using devise?

Comment: am using devise in dashboard_user.rb model @Rubyrider

Comment: okey, so the problem is somewhere, you are using current_user! Can you find that block first?

Comment: Am using only current_dashboard_user. after give load_and_authorize_resource only this error occur

Comment: I made an update in my answer. `helper_method: :current_user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, just do this trick for now. Somehow the current_user helper method is being called. So the quickest solution would be if you can do the following.

In your `application_controller.rb` file put this block:

```
   def current_user
    current_dashboard_user
   end

  # method_alias :current_user=, current_user # you may need this line if required.
   helper_method: :current_user
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: thanks. its solved but. now it shows error undefined method `CD_DASHBOARD_ADMIN?' for #<DashboardUser:0x007fa019ab4170>

Comment: That is different issue brother. We need to go through your model, why it is giving you the error.

Comment: Does my answer solve your specific problem regarding current_user?

Comment: i solved  undefined method `CD_DASHBOARD_ADMIN?' for #<DashboardUser:0x007fa019ab4170> error.

Comment: if current_dashboard_user.role_id==1? changed to this and it worked and now I have id'd defined for each user and this does not work  if current_dashboard_user.role_id==1?
         can :manage, :all
       else
         can :read, :summary
         can :read, :home
       end says it need end

Comment: hay can you create a separate question because this is something different.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9ccee7be3e7fa2df2bca   This is my assessment_controller